# Does CASCADE Delete execute as transaction?

Tags: sql, cascade

I want to perform cascade delete for some tables in my database, but I'm interested in what happens in case there's a failure when deleting something. Will everything rollback?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In general¹, yes, cascade deletes are done in the same transaction (or subtransaction) as your original delete. You should read the documentation of your SQL server, though.

¹ The exception is if you're using a database that doesn't support transactions, like MySQL with MyISAM tables.

Comment: In general? when are they not in a transaction?

Comment: Whe the database doesn't support transasctions for example. See MySQL with MyISAM tables...

Comment: @Cd-MaN MyISAM doesn't support foreign keys either, so you'd have to look pretty hard for a case where this exception comes into play.

Answer (score 5):

Cascade deletes are indeed atomic, they would be of little use without that property. It is in the documentation.

Comment: +1 for "they would be of little use without that property" :-) Very true.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth pointing out that *any* cascading event should be atomic (i.e. with in a transaction).  But, as Joel Coehoorn points out, check the documentation for your database.

Comment: Actually, it's not Joel Coehoorn that points that out. If unsure of the author, you better use "that answer" linking to its permalink.